# VBNET Reading a specific column on a line in a text file

Tags: vb.net, record

I have saved written a text file and it currently reads:

"first","surname","pass"

I want to read the password column so the 3rd one and define that as a variable. Its basically for a login, if pass in text file matches the entered pass (from user).

I have searched for about an hour now and no luck. Could someone guide me to a correct path.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a row.  You could call the password a field or a column, but certainly not a *row*.  Is this a CSV file?

Comment: read the line then use String.Split to get the parts

Comment: @StevenDoggart I am not sure, it is just a text file type. Sorry about the title, its columns yes. I simply want to read that 3rd column as all the usernames 1st row 3rd column will be the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example of reading a **small** file line by line and splitting each one into fields:

```
    ' get the values from the user somehow:
    Dim first As String = "James"
    Dim surname As String = "Bond"
    Dim pass As String = "007"

    Dim validated As Boolean = False ' assume wrong until proven otherwise

    ' check the file:
    Dim fileName As String = "c:\some folder\path\somefile.txt"
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName))
    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim values() As String = line.Split(",")
        If values.Length = 3 Then
            If values(0).Trim(Chr(34)) = first AndAlso
                values(1).Trim(Chr(34)) = surname AndAlso
                    values(2).Trim(Chr(34)) = pass Then
                validated = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' check the result
    If validated Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!")
    End If
```

Comment: When you say line by line do you mean you read each row field?

Comment: It reads each row (line) in the file, **and** separates out each row into columns (fields).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a CSV file, as seems to be the case, then the easiest way to read it will be with the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  [The MSDN already provides an excellent example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for how to use it to read a CSV file, so I won't bother reproducing it here.

Comment: Its just a .txt file. Text File Type.

Comment: CSV files are text files.  It's the *format* of the data in the text file that determines whether or not it is CSV.

Comment: Thank you i was looking for the "," comma separator, great way to determine rows.